# How to handle 2 different layouts in an activity Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[Edited]:
I have already developed one application which works well on different screen size phones and tablets, I followed as per android guidelines to create the different sets of UI layouts to cater with different sizes of screens(phones and tablets) and all layouts will be in portrait mode. Everything works fine till then but now I got one new requirement where the layouts of tablets will be changed i.e. **it will be having some extra information than phone layouts and all new layouts will be in landscape mode.**

Now my doubts are:

1. In old implementation, all layouts name are same in different layout folders i.e. layout,layout-small,layout-large etc... so , as per new requirement, all layouts of large and extra-large should be in landscape mode but if i keep the same name of layout then how do I handle the orientation? At present, orientation attribute mentioned in manifest file for each activity.
2. If I keep the different name of these layouts then I have to handle at run time i.e. while loading the activity,based on checking on phone screen size and then load the respective layout, so same activity can load different layout based on checking screen size. Will it be a optimal approach to do so?
3. OR,Do I have to altogether introduce new activities for all new layouts to handle this scenario?

Please suggest me best approach to handle this scenario.

Comment: You have been at SO long enough to know that this sort of question will get you a lot of negative votes as no attempt has been made by yourself to solve the problem. I would suggest you rephrase your question before the negative votes start. I won't downvote your post, but others might. ;)

Comment: You are Want opinion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would suggest you to name all similar files with the same name.**

Take full advantage of the qualifiers provided by Android like the size, or the set width qualifier.  You may have a single pane layout for small screen phones and multi pane layout for tablets. It's a good advice to provide multi pane layout ( you may combine two existing layouts into one ) for landscape orientation.

For example :

*res/layout/onepane.xml:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:id="@+id/frag1"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:name="com.example.android.dummyApp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
          </LinearLayout>
```

*res/layout/twopanes.xml:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragone"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:name="com.example.android.dummyApp"
          android:layout_width="400dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragtwo"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:name="com.example.android.dummyApp"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
         </LinearLayout>
```

Now that all possible layouts are defined, it's just a matter of mapping the correct layout to each configuration using the configuration qualifiers. You can now do it using the layout alias technique:

*res/values/layouts.xml:*

```
<resources>
<item name="main_layout" type="layout">@layout/onepane</item>
<bool name="has_two_panes">false</bool>
</resources>
```

*res/values-sw600dp-land/layouts.xml:*

```
<resources>
<item name="main_layout" type="layout">@layout/twopanes</item>
<bool name="has_two_panes">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Note : The bool values in the two xml files in values folder.

The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a certain minimum width given in dp. Instead of the large size qualifier, use sw600dp to indicate the two-pane layout is for screens on which the smallest-width is 600 dp.

**Also, another solution:**

If you are planning to make different activities for different screen sizes, you can build multiple apk for the same project. There should be a separate Android project for each APK you’re going to release.

Please look at this link for more information on Multiple APKs.
http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html

Comment: Upvoted because of not just linking to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, but copying the required information

Comment: Not the correct link :) @harvey_slash
but still helpful enough.

Answer (score 3):

A good point to start on this would be official Android documents (below links).

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

In a nutshell I can tell you would have to create multiple layouts to address your requirement for supporting multiple screen sizes/resolution. Within your application source directory you will have to create a different layout xml (with same name) under different resource-layout-directories as shown below:

```
 res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large screen devices (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large screen devices (landscape)
            main.xml
```

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I'd make two different Fragments, with two different Fragment Layouts, and I'd load the Fragment for the right screen size based on the layout folder identifier, like so: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Typical Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Button btnSave;
    private Button btnCancel;

    public MyFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment_small, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        btnSave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myfragment_small_save);
        btnCancel = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myfragment_small_cancel);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (btnSave == v)
        {
            save();
        }
        else if (btnCancel == v)
        {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

And do the same thing for the larger one. Bonus points if you reuse the save() and cancel() function by extending from MyFragment, or by ripping out the logic of them into another class.

Static fragment linking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_myfragment_small"
        android:name="com.example.stuff.longer.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And the layout for the fragment in fragment_myfragment_small.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button android:id="@+id/myfragment_small_cancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/myfragment_small_save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myfragment_small_cancel"
        android:text="@string/save"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And make a second one for the second, larger layout. Place the layout in a different \res\layout folder, such as \res\layout-large.

Comment: It MIGHT not be a perfect approach, apparently.

Oh well, I think it'd be nice.